# Pandas line chart Y label 1e6 instead of full number

Tags: python, pandas

[CLICK Here to see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tgi1F.png)

Hi everyone,

I have got a question relating to the Y label numbers. In my original dataframe all datas are full number such as 850,000; 200,000; 340,000 etc. However when I plot it into a line chart, it comes 1.0 e6 (please also see my attached pic).

Is there any way to plot the number comprehensively?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options

- format yourself after plotting
- change the formatter

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

df = pd.DataFrame({"A":np.random.randint(2*10**7,4*10**8, 20),
             "B":np.random.randint(2*10**7,4*10**8, 20),
})


fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, figsize=[10,6])

df.plot(ax=ax[0])
l = ax[0].set_yticklabels([f"{t/1000:0.0f}K" for t in ax[0].get_yticks()])
ax[1].yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.EngFormatter())
df.plot(ax=ax[1])
```

[image]